# How to remove space between TextField and Text on HStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a TextField and Text next in HStack Sections.
There is a large empty space between them and I can not figure out how to remove it.

```
VStack{

    Section {
        HStack {
            TextField("Kohalik raha", text: $localMoney)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Text("GEL")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        }
    }
    Section {
        Text("\(money, specifier: "%.2f") EUR")
    }
    Section {
        HStack {
            TextField("Kurss", text: $rate )
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Text("Kurss")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: [Picture from app]]

Answer (score 3):

Make the `textField` have `fixedSize` to bring them near in center:

```
HStack {
    TextField("Kohalik raha", text: $localMoney)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .fixedSize()

    Text("GEL")
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .background(Color.yellow)
}
```

[image: Preview]

I have added some colors to see better ;)

Comment: This worked for me with two buttons in an HStack. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a Spacer() after the TextField and Text views.